# Can we delete duplicate records from a table in teradata without using intermediate table

Tags: teradata

Can we delete duplicate records from a multiset table in teradata without using intermediate table.

Suppose we have 2 rows with values 
1, 2, 3 
and 1, 2, 3
in my multiset table then after delete i should have 
only one row i.e. 1, 2, 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't unless the ROWID usage has been enabled on your system (and probablity is quite low). You can easily test it by trying to explain a SELECT ROWID FROM table;

Otherwise there are two possible ways.

Low number of duplicates:

- create a new table as result of `SELECT all columns FROM table GROUP BY all columns HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;`
- `DELETE FROM tab WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM newtab WHERE...)`
- `INSERT INTO tab SELECT * FROM newtab`

High number of duplicates:

- copy to a new table using `SELECT DISTINCT *` or copy to a SET TABLE to get rid of the duplicates and then re-INSERT back

Answer (score 0):

Use the same approach, but create a volatile table in the middle.

CREATE VOLATILE MULTISET TABLE TEMPDB.TEMP_DUP_ID  (
    Row_ID DECIMAL(31,0)
) PRIMARY INDEX (Row_ID)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO TEMPDB.TEMP_DUP_ID
SELECT ROW_ID
FROM DB.TABLE T
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DUP ORDER BY DUP DESC) > 1

Then use the table to delete.

Ideally you will have unique key per row, otherwise, you will need to manipulate the data a bit more to generate one (with row_number() for instance... This is just a recommendation).

Answer (score 0):

---Without creating intermediate table

delete   FROM ORGINAL_TABLE  WHERE (COL1, 2) in (select  COL1, count(*) from ORGINAL_TABLE 
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(*) >1 )
and DUPLICATE_BASED_COL >1; -------Delete one row(keep it)

If you have duplicates and want to delete one row, then we need to use the last line in the sql, if we want to delete both rows than, ignore the condition.

Answer (score 0):

1. create table without dup

   ```
   CREATE TABLE new AS (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM old) WITH DATA;
   ```
2. verify

   ```
   select * from new;
   ```
3. drop the original one

   ```
   drop table old;
   ```
4. rename the new table as original

   ```
   RENAME TABLE new to old;
   ```
5. verify

   ```
   select * from old;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

SEL * FROM THE_TABLE_Containing_duplications
QUALIFY (ROW_number() over(partition by duplicated_column order by duplicated_column)=1)  --keep only one occurence (the first one)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).