# Delete 1000 duplicates from a table contain 10 million record in Teradata

Tags: sql, duplicates, teradata, query-performance

I came across below question in one of the interview process.

A table "TableA" contains 10 million records. There are almost a 1000 duplicate records in it. How can we delete those duplicates in the most efficient way?

Can someone please help out with the most performance efficient solution?

The solution which I came up with is,

Create Temp table:
create table tmp as (select distinct * from TableA) with data

Drop Original Table

Re Insert data from Tmp to TableA

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19549032/2527905

Answer (score 0):

I don' have a teradata to give it a try.
But you can use something like this:

```
delete 
from table 
where table.rowid not in 
(
select max(table.rowid) 
from table 
group by col1,col2,col3.....
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take Primary column in your select statement from table .
eg.: EmailID, Mobile, Or Any Unique Primary Key Value and try this Query.
/

select t1.column1, t1.column2 from table1 t1 where( t1.column , t1.column2) in ( select t2.column1, t2.column2 from table1 t2 group by t2.column1, t2.column2 having count(*)>1);

Answer (score 0):

Because the volume of the hypothetical table is so large, using a volatile table to hold deduped records is probably the smartest way to go. It may also be the most efficient (haven't tested that though).

Something like the following would make sense:

```
/*A hypothetical very large table*/
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE testtable
(
    f1 integer,
    f2 integer,
    f3 DATE
) 
    PRIMARY INDEX (f1, f2) 
    ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO testtable VALUES (1,1, DATE '2017-01-01');
INSERT INTO testtable VALUES (1,2, DATE '2017-01-01');
INSERT INTO testtable VALUES (1,1, DATE '2017-02-01');
INSERT INTO testtable VALUES (1,3, DATE '2017-01-01');
INSERT INTO testtable VALUES (1,3, DATE '2017-01-03');

/*assuming a key of f1 and f2 to identify a duplicate
 *and assuming that if we encounter a duplicate we want
 *to keep the newest one by the f3 date, then:
 *generate a volatile table to hold deduped recordsa
 *using a QUALIFY clause to perform duplicate identification
 */
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE testtable_dedup AS
(
    SELECT * FROM testtable
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f1, f2 /*key*/ ORDER BY f3 desc /*date for each key sorted descending*/) = 1 /*keep the newest record*/
) WITH DATA 
 PRIMARY INDEX (f1, f2)
 ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

/*show what records are being dropped*/
SELECT * FROM testtable
MINUS
SELECT * FROM testtable_dedup;

/*Delete everything*/
DELETE FROM testtable ALL;

/*And reload from the dedup volatile table*/
INSERT INTO testtable SELECT * FROM testtable_dedup;

SELECT * FROM testtable;

/*Clean up*/
DROP TABLE testtable_dedup;
DROP TABLE testtable;
```